# Will Windows 8  increase the memory cap of  2 GB?

Tags: memory, windows-8-preview

I have a old Dell Latitude D430 laptop that I just upgraded to Windows 8. The RAM that I have installed is 2 GB (this is the max RAM that this laptop can handle). I am wondering if by installing Windows 8 I can increase the cap of the total RAM that the laptop can handle.

I know that some laptops have a cap of RAM by the BIOS but I am wondering if any of you know if installing a new OS can actually change this?

Comment: Most probably not. The limit is in the hardware, not software, so it will apply no matter what OS you're using.

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately not - technically it is not the BIOS that limits the memory, it is the chipset of the motherboard - and this does not change, no matter which operating system you install.

The chipset is what (traditionally) connects the majority of the parts of the motherboard to each other, and this is where the limit comes from.

Comment: Bios can limit memory if they wrote it that way, and I have seen a few systems that did just that.

Answer (score 0):

No.  The cap is based on hardware, not software.